# re_object_detector_gui

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I use the roboearth_stack  and follow the Tutorials on "Record an object model" ,
it is something wrong ,when I type

rosrun re_object_recorder record_gui

it shows

Couldn't find executable named record_gui below /home/hank/roboearth/stacks/roboearth/object_scanning/re_object_recorder

does anyone know why ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56826/re_object_detector_gui/) by [hank](https://answers.ros.org/users/4333/hank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Call [rosmake](http://ros.org/wiki/rosmake) on that package:

`rosmake re_object_recorder`

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0